# onhashchange not firing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope

I'm creating a portfolio using wordpress and [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/). I want to use the onhashchange event so that when a user uses the back and forward buttons isotope updates properly. To test the onhashchange function I added this code to my js file:

```
     if ("onhashchange" in window) {
     alert("The browser supports the hashchange event!");
}
```

The problem is that this function only runs when the page loads and never runs when the hash changes. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just checking if the browser supports it,  but not *assigning* any `function` to  the handler, which would act as the callback

```
if("onhashchange" in window) {
    window.onhashchange = function(){
       alert("Hash changed!");
    }
}
```

Comment: @TovlyDeutsch if it helped, don't forget to mark it as answer by clicking on the tick.. BTW, glad to have helped :)